# Histogram if condition error C++

Tags: c++, histogram

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    ifstream in;
    ofstream out;

    int col, row;
    in.open("intrare.txt");
    in >> col >> row;
    int v[col][row];
    for (int y=0;y<col;y++) {
        for (int x=0;x<row;x++) {
            in >> v[y][x];
        }
    }
    in.close();

    int val[row];
    for (int j=0;j<row;j++)
        val[j]=0;


    int area=0, marea=0;
    vector<int> _stack;

    for (int i=0;i<col;i++) {

        for (int k=0;k<row;k++) {
            if (v[i][k]==0)
                val[k]++;
            else
                val[k]=0;
        }

        for (int j=0;j<row-1;j++)
            if (val[j]<=val[j+1] && val[j]!=0)
                _stack.push_back(j);
    }
    out.open("iesire.txt");
    out << marea;
    out.close();
    return 0;
}
```

This takes the values from a bi-dimensional array and converts it in a histogram if the number at the certain indexes is, in my case, either a 0 or 1. What I'm trying to do is to calculate the maximum area rectangle from the histogram, with the stack method (I'm using vector instead of stack). The 2nd nested `for` loop pushes back the index if certain conditions are true. My problem is that for some weird reason, the program, when compiled, doesn't respond and quits. The problem is the `val[j]!=0` as of because the program runs just fine when i remove the condition. I really can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you want help with code you need to show us the code. There is no way I could run this snippet (unless i do a lot of guessing to make it compile). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I sure hope the size of `val` is `row+1` or you will go out of bounds.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It is.

Comment: @tobi303 There's really not much more I really have to paste in in order for you to understand the problem. I think the code I've pasted in sums up the problem

Comment: It cannot be that there is not much more. That code alone does not compile. None of the variables are declared. Depending on the types, this snippet could do anything

Comment: And the value in `val[row]` have been initialized? Also, have you tried running in a debugger to catch a possible crash? Of stepped through the code line by line?

Comment: @tobi303 I've edited the post. I've pasted in the entire code

Comment: and this code still crashes? Just asking, because the offbyone error is fixed now

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes I've used a for loop to set them all to 0 and the to increment them if the value was 0 or set them back to 0 if the value was 1

Comment: @tobi303 Yes. I really got no clue why this is happening

Comment: Maybe you should print out the values row and col that are read from file, just to check that these are not garbage (say, negative values).

Comment: What are the values of `row` and `col`? And you do know that C++ doesn't really have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)? Use `std::vector` instead.